# Problema con FirebaseListAdapter, no aparece la lista

Tags: java, android, firebase

¿Por qué no me aparece nada en la emulacion con este código?

```
Firebase rootRef = PantallaPrincipal.rootRef;  
ListView lista_cursos;  
@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cursos);  
    lista_cursos = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_cursos);  
}  

@Override  
protected void onStart() {  
    super.onStart();  
    Firebase cursosRef = rootRef.child("Cursos");  
    FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>  
   (this,String.class,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cursosRef){  
        @Override  
        protected void populateView(View view, String s, int i) {  
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);  
            textView.setText(s);  
        }  
    };  
    lista_cursos.setAdapter(adapter);  
}
```

Intento hacer que aparezcan los datos que hay en la DataBase de Firebase en un listView.

Comment: Victor , que es cursosRef? podrías agregar el Código ?

Comment: Es la instancia de un hijo de rootRef ( Direccion raiz de la DateBase de Firebase) Ya modifico para que veas bien.

Comment: El único hijo de rootRef que veo es usersRef y no cursoref

Comment: Listo ahora si, lo siento pegue el codigo que no era.

Comment: podrias incluir tu bd en firebase?

Answer (score 2):

En el FirebaseListAdapter estas usando  `cursosRef` :

```
   FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>  (this,String.class,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cursosRef){
```

en tu FirebaseListAdapter debes usar una instancia de la Firebase , por ejemplo:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://ejemplo.firebaseio.com/msg");
FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>  (this,String.class,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ref ){
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Si, eso es cursosRef ... Es la instancia que referencia a una de las ramas de la raiz de la base de datos .